# Burinate-request: [program]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, meta-tags

The tag [program](/questions/tagged/program) should be burinated. It seems all the questions with it were cleared at some point in the past, but [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082463/programming-an-mp3-player) has appeared with it recently, as well as a second, which I edited to remove the tag. It adds nothing to the question, and could not stand alone.

Comment: cover it in sugar and let a bundle of fire ants burn it... then nuke it.... so, yes, agree

Comment: @UV-D not just any fire ants, giant fallout fire ants. They need that radiation power!

Answer (score 4):

I removed the tag from that question so the tag should disappear in a day or so.

Comment: We only blacklist egregiously bad tags like [subjective], [homework] and [never-friday-in-sweden].

Comment: @Robert: Alright.

Comment: I've added it to my list of tags I keep dead daily.  The current tally of deaded tags is **85**.

Comment: WTH is [tag:never-friday-in-sweden]?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21413